# grails 2.4.4, how to do pagination with very large record set, so dont know the total

Tags: grails, pagination

All the examples I can find do something like this:

```
 <g:paginate controller="Book" action="list" total="${bookInstanceTotal}" />
```

and the total attribute is "required" according to the [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Tags/paginate.html).

This works fine for very simple examples with small record sets (e.g. a few hundred)

If there are say 100k rows returned because the user put in wide search criteria, then I certainly don't want to read them all to find the total to allow pagination, and don't want to transfer all 100k rows from the db to the grails server, and don't want to repeat this each time thy hit the next page. I want to use the mysql limit/offset or similar to only bring back the small number of required rows.

Is this possible, or do I really have to work out the total (by reading all the records, or doing a separate count, then read the records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will always prefer to use criteria for pagination.

The example of using criteria :

```
def c = Account.createCriteria()
def results = c.list (max: 10, offset: 10) {
    like("holderFirstName", "Fred%")
    and {
        between("balance", 500, 1000)
        eq("branch", "London")
    }
    order("holderLastName", "desc")
}
```

This example is taken from [grails documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) and you can read more about criteria in [this documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html).

Using this criteria, you will get at max 10 results. But the important part is you can get total count according to the same criteria by using

`results.totalCount`

Comment: Domain.list() does the same if you need just a simple list without additional criteria / filters, Domain.list is easiest way to go. and it does provide results.totalCount and sorting / ordering. when you have specified the max parameter. Read docs for list() method again,

Comment: This could be the answer, as I have a more complex query.  This construct looked like it would query all rows, then run the closure in code on the result (= very inefficient).  Having looked at the links you included, am I right in thinking that the closure actually generates a proper select, only returning the required rows?

Comment: If the results of this list query are going to be used in a table with sortable columns, then I presume we would need to manually construct the order part using the order field and direction specified in the params, rather than hard code to one of the fields as in the example?

Comment: No No. It will not query all the rows and it is not inefficient. It will get only the results according to max value and the closure is the condition which is used to get data from the database. It will not query all the rows and filter using the closure.

Comment: For order part, you can do order(fieldName, sortOrder) where fieldName and sortOrder are variables and can be set accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't read all records from db and load in grails to get the total. You just load 10 or whatever number of records you display in each page and you execute a count query to get the totalCount.

It works like this.

Lets say, you display 10 records on each page and you have 100K records in db.
Lets say UI passes max and offset params.

```
params.max = params.max ? (params.int(max) < 100 : params.max : 100) : 10
params.offset = params.offset ?: 0

def list = Domain.list(params)
```

When max option is specified, Domain.list() method returns PagedResultList which has getTotalCount() method which fires a count query and returns totalCount.

And you render the view like this

```
render(view:"list", model:[list:list, totalCount:list.totalCount)
```

So here you are not loading all the records from database, you are loading just 10 records and execute a count query to get totalCount

Comment: @Ramsharan - you are wrong.read docs again.
See this link http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/list.html and delete your comment and remove the negative vote: dont vote negative if you are not sure

Comment: Thank you for the link. You are right. Normally I use findAllBy or criteria and I rarely use list method.

Comment: Thanks sudhir.  Unfortunately, I cant use the list method, as I need to use a findByXXX method, e.g. findAllByPlayer(player, params).  Unfortunately, the restult of this does not seem to have a totalCount or getTotalCount function or attribute

Comment: @JohnLittle If you prefer to use findAllBy. Then you can use findAllByPlayer(player, params) and countByPlayer(player) to get total count.